# How do I brew with nuts? Specifically hazelnuts.

Tags: adjuncts, nuts

I want to make a beer with some hazelnut flavor to it. Maybe add some cocoa nibs or powder to the wort and make a Nutella-ish beer. My question itself is specific to hazelnuts, but maybe you could enlighten me on how to brew with all types of edible nuts?

My questions/concerns are:

1. **How do I prepare the hazelnuts for the beer?** Would I roast them in the oven first? I'll need to de-shell them first, correct?
2. **Will the fat content cause the beer to spoil?** That what makes Nutella so delicious of course, but fat in beer sounds terrible. Is there anyway to avoid that?
3. **When would I add them to the beer?** Mash? Boil? Secondary? Depends?

There are probably other things that I'll need to consider. But if anyone could help me out from experience, it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the safest way to add hazelnut flavor to beer would be to use hazelnut extract. If you don't want to use pre-bought extract/syrup, you can make your own by chopping up the nuts, covering them with vodka (or another neutral spirit), leave it for a few days, strain off the vodka and add it to the fermenter after a couple of days of fermenting. If the vodka contains fat after the nuts are removed, skim it off with a (sterilized!) spoon.

Comment: I agree with the extract route.  Rogue makes an award winning hazelnut brown ale using extract.

Comment: How much vodka and how many nuts? I tried this method and it did not work out for me. The extract had hazelnut flavor but, I guess not enough as you could not taste it in the final beer. I skinned 1/2 cup of hazelnuts (is this necessary) and chopped them up and mixed them with 4 oz of 100 proof vodka. I let it all sit for a month and then strained out the vodka and added that to the 5 gallon second fermentation. Was this not enough nuts or enough vodka?

Comment: Isn't fat soluble in alcohol?

Answer (score 6):

You want to be careful adding nuts as they are very fatty. Introduction of lipids in beer can cause a lot of problems. Using powders and/or extracts is recommended. You can introduce nuts during the boil however, but you'll need to skim the contents that float to the top during the process. Still I would avoid using actual nuts.